# UINavigationController in UITabBarController: NavigationItems disappear in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationitem

I have an iPad application compatible with iOS 5.1 or higher. I'm updating the app for iOS 7.
I have this problem: I have a UINavigationController inside a UITabBarController. I want to add rightBarButtonItems. With iOS 6 or lower are seen, but with iOS 7 no. What I'm wrong?

PS: I'm forced to make app compatible with iOS 5.1 because there are some customers who are still using the first generation of iPad, so I can't use AutoLayout. I'm XIB because the project is a pretty old and I haven't to rewrite code.

Thank you!!

edit for Nikos M.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[...];
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB3Rc.png

Edit 2:

I had tried to add a custom view on navigation bar:

```
//I added this line otherwise I not see the Navigation Bar!!
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 132)];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:[self addTableHeader]];
```

and this is the result!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aksqb.png

Comment: Paste some code where you show how you put the barbuttonitems to the navbar in order to help you.

Comment: check this, it will give some idea., http://stuartkhall.com/posts/ios-7-development-tips-tricks-hacks i can't understand what is your problem

Comment: Nikos M., I've edit question.

karthika: no, those tricks not help me :(

Comment: Maybe try     self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems ?

Comment: Akash Malhotra: I had already tried, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in iOS 7. Try this.

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"ONE" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil], nil];
```

[image]

Comment: in a new project this works, but on this project doesn't work. thank you!

Comment: maybe try changing Base SDK?

Comment: As I have said before, I can't do that. The app must be compatible with iOS 5.1 or higher.

Comment: you are confusing Base SDk with deployment target